# C++ socketing on Ubuntu server

Tags: c++, sockets, ubuntu

i am a novice programmer and wish to get into server side programming, i already have my Ubuntu server up and running and ran a few programs i created, i wish to use c++ on my server as i am using the same language on my client side, i cannot seem to find a good library to handle socketing on Ubuntu as i wish to create a networked application next,

I already tried to  search for one but all i keep finding C libraries i would appreciate any tutorial or library to a C++ socket library on Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)?

[ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) is another one

Also I am a huge fan of [Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qtnetwork-index.html)

Comment: just checked Boost.Asio, it looks promising thank you for your quick response i will go read their tutorial.